# No activity on server with logging every 5 seconds

Tags: linux, bash, logging, ssh, logrotate

Recently I have notices that log files on my server grow faster than I was expecting. After a quick look I have realized that it is `wtmp` what aggressively is taking my disk space. Using `utmpdump` command (see below) I found out that **every 5 seconds** new 3 or 4 logs are recorded.

```
# utmpdump /var/log/wtmp | tail -n 25
Utmp dump of /var/log/wtmp
[6] [00886] [2   ] [LOGIN   ] [tty2        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:08 2018 MSK]
[8] [00885] [1   ] [        ] [tty1        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:13 2018 MSK]
[6] [00889] [1   ] [LOGIN   ] [tty1        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:13 2018 MSK]
[8] [00886] [2   ] [        ] [tty2        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:13 2018 MSK]
[6] [00890] [2   ] [LOGIN   ] [tty2        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:13 2018 MSK]
[8] [00889] [1   ] [        ] [tty1        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:18 2018 MSK]
[6] [00897] [1   ] [LOGIN   ] [tty1        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:18 2018 MSK]
[8] [00890] [2   ] [        ] [tty2        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:18 2018 MSK]
[6] [00898] [2   ] [LOGIN   ] [tty2        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:18 2018 MSK]
[8] [00897] [1   ] [        ] [tty1        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:23 2018 MSK]
[6] [00899] [1   ] [LOGIN   ] [tty1        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:23 2018 MSK]
[8] [00898] [2   ] [        ] [tty2        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:23 2018 MSK]
[6] [00900] [2   ] [LOGIN   ] [tty2        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:23 2018 MSK]
[8] [00899] [1   ] [        ] [tty1        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:28 2018 MSK]
[6] [00901] [1   ] [LOGIN   ] [tty1        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:28 2018 MSK]
[8] [00900] [2   ] [        ] [tty2        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:28 2018 MSK]
[6] [00902] [2   ] [LOGIN   ] [tty2        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:28 2018 MSK]
[8] [00901] [1   ] [        ] [tty1        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:33 2018 MSK]
[6] [00906] [1   ] [LOGIN   ] [tty1        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:33 2018 MSK]
[8] [00902] [2   ] [        ] [tty2        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:33 2018 MSK]
[6] [00907] [2   ] [LOGIN   ] [tty2        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:33 2018 MSK]
[8] [00906] [1   ] [        ] [tty1        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:38 2018 MSK]
[6] [00910] [1   ] [LOGIN   ] [tty1        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:38 2018 MSK]
[8] [00907] [2   ] [        ] [tty2        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:38 2018 MSK]
[6] [00911] [2   ] [LOGIN   ] [tty2        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Wed Feb 07 17:26:38 2018 MSK]
```

There is no load on the server:

```
# w
 17:34:03 up 17 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/2    cpe-75-177-130-5 17:24    0.00s  0.02s  0.00s w
```

And no strange processes ruining:

```
# top
top - 17:35:08 up 18 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks:  28 total,   1 running,  27 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.3%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2097152k total,    47060k used,  2050092k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,    28024k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 1141 root      20   0 11452 3536 2724 S  1.3  0.2   0:00.11 sshd
    1 root      20   0  2844 1440 1228 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.27 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd/9506
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper/9506
   72 root      16  -4  2560  600  364 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 udevd
   98 root      18  -2  2556  604  364 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 udevd
   99 root      18  -2  2556  604  364 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 udevd
  458 root      20   0  9400 1008  520 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 sshd
  469 root      20   0  3144  940  760 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xinetd
  483 root      20   0  6224  576  264 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 vsftpd
  494 root      20   0  8704  864  468 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 saslauthd
  496 root      20   0  8704  552  156 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 saslauthd
  514 root      20   0 12352 1820  708 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.01 sendmail
  521 smmsp     20   0 12152 1624  644 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sendmail
  533 root      20   0 25096 6956 3932 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.03 httpd
  543 root      20   0  1964  496  436 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
  544 root      20   0  1964  488  436 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
  552 root      20   0  1964  492  436 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
  554 root      20   0  1964  488  436 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
  556 root      20   0  1964  492  436 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
  558 root      20   0  1964  492  436 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
  559 apache    20   0 25096 3676  628 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 httpd
  831 root      20   0 12572 3652 2908 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.06 sshd
  833 root      20   0  6372 1712 1472 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.02 bash
 1136 root      20   0  2548 1076  892 R  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 top
 1142 sshd      20   0 10744 1452  876 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.01 sshd
 1145 root      20   0  1960  592  532 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
 1146 root      20   0  1960  596  532 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
```

What is behind these log records and why such tasks are recorded every 5 seconds? Is there a way to stop record those "dummy" logs and have only real login logs recorded?

Comment: Once I had a shortcut on my serial port, sending '\0' chars all the time to the login program listening on that port. Could it be such a hardware problem?

Comment: [Here](http://xmodulo.com/monitor-user-login-history-centos-utmpdump.html) there's a good explanation on wtmp raw format. So, in your case, it's a local process the one generating the output denoted by the 0.0.0.0 column. I would inspect cron jobs running, /var/log/messages file for any unusual activity and if possible the physical status of the server.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz - There is no `crond` installed on this server. The file `/var/log/messages` is empty (0 bytes).

Comment: try journalctl command or investigate which logging method it's using

Comment: @LuisMuñoz - `-bash: journalctl: command not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record all processes running during 50 seconds

`for i in {1..10} ; do ps -efH | tee -a ~/tmp/pids-5.txt;  sleep 5; done`

Then dump wtmp contents and check second column values against pids-5.txt. It should tell you which user and command the PID belongs to.
You could then do something to avoid those process running.

Comment: Thanks. The logs belong to `/sbin/mingetty /dev/tty1` and `/sbin/mingetty /dev/tty2`

Comment: so something is restarting your physical consoles at the server. May be because they can't be configured and keeps retrying

Comment: Thanks, but I see no way to configure `mingetty` or to disable its dummy logs

Comment: Check [here](https://github.com/scaleway/image-debian/issues/81) and [here](https://github.com/lxc/linuxcontainers.org/issues/134).